# How to open jupyter with preview notebook editor by default

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

[github.com/microsoft/vscode-jupyter](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-jupyter) says that I have to add the following code:

```
"jupyter.experiments.optOutFrom": ["NativeNotebookEditor"]
```

in my `settings.json` file like so

[image]

But it doesn't work, even after removing

```
"workbench.editorAssociations": {"*.ipynb": "jupyter-notebook"}
```

Does anybody know how to solve this?

Comment: The VSCode settings provided in `settings.json` are fallback only. If your extension finds a config file (editorconfig or any other) then only those will be used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems has been removed:

> This is by design. The Native Notebook editor is no longer an
> experiment. Sorry we didn't tell you.

refer to [here](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-jupyter/issues/7091)